# Javascript: Chaining .split method results in TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, string, split, chaining

I have a block of XML text that I would like to split up to create an object. Let's say it looks like this (only information in the tag has been changed). This is the variable xmlArray[i]:

```
<title><![CDATA[Jumping Jack]]></title>
<date><![CDATA[Oct 5, 2017]]></date>
<referencenumber><![CDATA[1234]]></referencenumber>
<url><![CDATA[https://www.google.com]]></url>
<company><![CDATA[Jumping Jacks' Jigs]]></company>
<city><![CDATA[North Pole]]></city>
<state><![CDATA[AL]]></state>
<country><![CDATA[US]]></country>
```

When I try the following code in order to get the title information by itself:

```
var title = xmlArray[i].split("<title><![CDATA[")[1].split("]]")[0];
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined (pointing to the second decimal/period before the second split)
```

However, when I try to look at the first half of that split without chaining the second one, ie:

```
var title = xmlArray[i].split("<title><![CDATA[")[1];
```

I am able to see:

```
JumpingJack]]></title><date><![CDATA[Oct5,2017]]></date><referencenumber><![CDATA[1234]]></referencenumber><url><![CDATA[https://www.gogle.com]]></url><company><![CDATA[Jumping Jacks' Jigs]]></company><city><![CDATA[North Pole]]></city><state><![CDATA[AL]]></state><country><![CDATA[US]]>
```

The formatting looks strange above but whitespace isn't the problem (I don't think). Is it obvious to anyone why I am unable to access this string and split it with the second, chained "split"?

Comment: And you don't want to use the XML parser [built into every browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) (even IE 9) because?

Comment: @JaredSmith because reasons™!

Comment: Because I didn't know it existed. Not really an answer to my question, but thanks for the new avenue!

Comment: @lumel not trying to be offensive in pointing out the obvious, but converting tag-based markup into objects is *what a browser does*. HTML is a subset of XML.

Comment: No offense taken.

Comment: at face value, assuming `xmlArray[i]` contains that block of xml as you say it does, your code is fine.  I am only able to reproduce this error by making `xmlArray[i]` not exist. IOW it seems to me your problem isn't with your chained split, but with your (i assume) loop (since you have `[i]`) and attempt to reference an index of `xmlArray` that does not exist

Comment: @lumel if you ever tell anyone I gave you this I'll call you a filthy liar but `xmlData[i].match(/CDATA\[(.+)\]/g)`. Realistically though this will fail for any nesting and you should use the XML parser.

Comment: you're the bomb j-rod but I'm going to go with an npm package XML parser seeing as how I'm trying to do this in the backend (probably should have put that in the question, sorry). Thanks for the tip! :)